# How to read pdf file from raw folder?

Tags: java, android

I want to read the pdf file from raw folder if devices have any pdfreader..
Here is my code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
              Uri.parse("android.resource://com.powergroupbd.pdfreader/raw" + R.raw.androidtasksmwp));

    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    if (activities.size() > 0) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No pdfreader  found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

But when i run this project it shows error.here is the logcat result:

```
06-21 02:05:04.408: W/dalvikvm(7763): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.qo.android.htcgep/com.qo.android.am.pdflib.app.RenderScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at com.qo.android.am.pdflib.app.RenderScreen.onNewIntent(Unknown Source)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at com.qo.android.am.pdflib.app.RenderScreen.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-21 02:05:04.418: E/AndroidRuntime(7763):  ... 11 more
06-21 02:05:04.418: W/ActivityManager(96):   Force finishing activity com.qo.android.htcgep/com.qo.android.am.pdflib.app.RenderScreen
```

What i am doing wrong? please help..:(

Comment: One of your objects is not being properly initialized, so it's throwing a null pointer exception - trying to act on a null pointer to something (in this case an object).

Comment: you have try as `Uri.parse("android.resource://com.powergroupbd.pdfreader/raw/androidtasksmwp"));`

Comment: Which object i should initialize for this? :(

Comment: or `Uri.parse("android.resource://com.powergroupbd.pdfreader/" + R.raw.androidtasksmwp));`

Comment: I try this.but it shows the same result for Uri.parse("android.resource://com.powergroupbd.pdfreader/" + R.raw.androidtasksmwp));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried to do it the way you do, but I use raw resources quite successfully via following procedure:

1. Get and InputStream for resource via

   > fileResourceStream =
   >   Activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.androidclient));//R file
   >   references the resource id for you. In your case it will be
   >   R.raw.androidtasksmwp.
2. Using this InputStream I copy (usually once the application is installed) the resource file to either device memory or SD card (decision is yours).
     Something like this can be devised:

   ```
   BufferedInputStream bIS = new BufferedInputStream(
   fileResourceStream);
   try {
           BufferedOutputStream bOS = new BufferedOutputStream(
           new FileOutputStream(Globals.applicationDirPath
                   + Globals.exeFileName, false));

           int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
           byte[] buff = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
           int bytesRead = bIS.read(buff, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
           while (bytesRead >= 0) {
               bOS.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
               bytesRead = bIS.read(buff, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
           }
           bIS.close();
           bOS.flush();
           bOS.close();
   }// try {
   catch (Exception e) {
           Globals.log("Exception in checkAndCopyClientToMemory."
           + e.toString());
   }
   ```
3. Open copied file in any application/for any purpose as file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing a "/" after ".../raw" so the uri is incorrect.

`Uri.parse("android.resource://com.powergroupbd.pdfreader/raw" + R.raw.androidtasksmwp)`

However I'm not sure you can access resources from an external package like this you may need to copy it to the sdcard then open it with an intent

Comment: so if i want to read pdf file from resource folder ,it is not possible?

Comment: The file is private to your application.  If you want to use it you must copy it to somewhere public like the sdcard